# Create string of nth li's in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, css-selectors

How do I create a string of each 3rd li, resulting in

```
black,red,blue
```

from this:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>shirt</li>
        <li>x-large</li>
        <li>black</li>
        <li>9.99</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>pants</li>
        <li>large</li>
        <li>red</li>
        <li>19.99</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>shoes</li>
        <li>medium</li>
        <li>blue</li>
        <li>9.99</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$(function () {
   var result = [];
   $('#container ul').find('li:eq(2)').each(function () {
      result.push($(this).text());
   });

   result.join();

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BxJbH/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nth-child(3)` to get all elements that are third children:

```
var colors = [];
$("#container").find('li:nth-child(3)').text(function (_, text) {
    colors.push(text);
});
console.log(colors.join(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/CfrWX/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array you can use `+=` to concatenate you string:

```
myString = "";
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
    myString += ","+$(this).text();
})
console.log(myString.substring(1));
// returns 'black,red,blue'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/phtMx/

Answer (score 1):

```
var concatenated = $.map($('li:nth-child(3)'), function(a, i) {
    return $(a).html();
}).join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers have said, use the [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$(function(){
    var strings = $('#container').find('li:nth-child(3)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(', ');
    $('#result').text(strings);
});
```

Demo - http://jsbin.com/efavor/2/edit